# Which nuget package contains the method GetSheetService()?

Tags: c#, google-api, nuget-package, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to know whether there is a nuget package that contains GetSheetService(), I can't find which is the right package, anyone know this? Has anyone used this method?

This are the packages that I had installed:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis" Version="1.40.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.40.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc" Version="1.40.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" Version="1.40.3.1694" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.28" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and this is the problem I have encountered:
[image]

this is the start of the cs file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
```

Comment: That's a method in the current class. Please explain your scenario. That method doesn't exist in the Sheets package. Did you copy some code from elsewhere? Then copy along the relevant methods.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is actually part of someone else's problem, I know azure function. But the question he asked about has some Google API issues, I don't understand this. It’s just that I am very curious about this. I would be very grateful if anyone could give some help!I googled, but can't find the current package.

Comment: This is the questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762233/azure-functions-the-given-assembly-name-or-codebase-was-invalid-exception-fr/57764480#57764480

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you solve his problem? I am a newcomer to Google API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google .net client library does not have a method called get sheets service.  I suspect you are copying this from someones code some places. The correct way to create a sheets service follows

```
/// <summary>
    /// This method get a valid service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credential">Authecated user credentail</param>
    /// <returns>SheetsService used to make requests against the Sheets API</returns>
    private static SheetsService GetService(UserCredential credential)
    {
        try
        {
            if (credential == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("credential");

            // Create Sheets API service.
            return new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Sheets Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Get Sheets service failed.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Code ripped from my google .net client Library sample project. [Oauth2Authentication.cs)](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Sheets%20API/v4/Oauth2Authentication.cs)