# Serialize a class using XML

Tags: c#

After watching more than 3 hours of tutoring I can't find an answer:

I'm trying to serialize a class here:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Gestionnaire_d_Établissement_Scolaire
{
    public class Resources
    {
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public List<Etablissement> Etablissements { get; set; }

        public string Path_Etablissement = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Etablissements.xml";
        public string Path_Teacher = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Teachers.xml";
        public string Path_Student = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Students.xml";

        public void LoadAll()
        {

        }

        public void AddTeacher()
        {

        }

        public void AddEtablissement()
        {
            var doc = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resources));

                serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            }

            doc.Save(Path_Etablissement);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But this code gives me an error as follows:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: The name or base code of the given assembly is not valid. (HRESULT exception: 0x80131047)

Frenziedly I am lost and I have no solution. It's at the line:

```
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resources));
```

Thank you for helping me

---

EDIT

And if you - you ask yourself it's only the 3 lists I want to serialize, but it really doesn't matter if the path variables are also taken

Comment: See if any of the suggestions here help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520212/exception-from-hresult-0x80131047

Comment: This doen't repro for me in a new .NET Framework console application.  Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization#security-considerations-for-xmlserializer-applications for possible causes involving the dynamic XML serialization assembly, and include additional details about the exception (eg full stack trace) and your applicaiton.

Comment: Without seeing the 3 classes used in the lists it's just guesswork.

Answer (score -4):

Try using a GET :

```
        public string Path_Etablissement
        {
            get { return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Etablissements.xml"; }
        }
        public string Path_Teacher
        {
            get { return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Teachers.xml"; }
        }
        public string Path_Student
        {
            get { return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire d'établissement Scolaire\Students.xml"; }
        }
```

Comment: Why is this a solution?

Comment: @Tom : Do you know what is actually failing?  Don't give negative points without understanding the issue.

Comment: @jdweng, Then, if you know this is the solution and know what is actually failing, you should explain that in your answer. Don't just put the code.

Comment: @jdweng do you?