# WPF UserControl Given Assembly Name or Codebase is Invalid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, visual-studio-2022

I am learning WPF right now and building a simple application to generate an Ulam Spiral. Right now I want to implement my own spinner when the program is calculating the spiral. My plan is to create a UserControl as the spinner and then display it in the main window.

However, when I am testing the spinner in the main window, I got "Given assembly name or codebase is invalid" error. I've tested using a completely empty solution, it worked. But, if I use it in my project, it does not work. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, it still does not work. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can somebody help me? I'm attaching the whole solution [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgOO_inpY5SKgowg_YTe6RKsJnOalQ?e=bvxChq). I'm really frustrated right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code doing the following:

1. Visual Studio -> remove `'` from your project's name to be `Ulams Spiral` instead of `Ulam's Spiral` ([following this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528472/4108016))
2. Visual Studio -> Build -> Configuration Manager -> new Platform : add x64
3. Note that you have an error in `MainWindow.xaml` -> Replace `<local:Spinner />` with `<local:UlamSpinner />`
4. Rebuild and run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It works at the first step. I don't know that small thing can cause a big headache. I'll remind myself not to use ' in my project name in the future.